# Calculating $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(N+1+n)(N+n)}$ by hand

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

In a recent proof I used induction to prove an identity concerning the harmonic progressions:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N+n} $$ 
I needed to know what the following sum equaled so I used Wolfram Alpha to find, $N \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(N+1+n)(N+n)}=\frac{N}{2N^2+3N+1}$$

**However, that got me thinking how you could go about finding that result without the help of a computer.**

**Where would one even start? Try to manipulate it into a known format, where you already know a formula?**

Comment: It looks like it's a telescoping summation. Have you tried partial fraction decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I got $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N+n} - \frac{1}{N+n+1} = \frac{1}{N+1} - \frac{1}{2N+1}$ and it's just simplifying from there. For some reason I didn't see the telescopic summation!

Comment: It's probably due to the vicious way the factors are written!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:$$\frac { 1 }{ (N+1+n)(N+n) } =\frac { 1 }{ N+n } -\frac { 1 }{ N+n+1 } $$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{1}{(N+n+1)(N+n)} = \frac{1}{N+n} - \frac{1}{N+n+1}, $$
and summing, the middle terms cancel and one is left with
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(N+n+1)(N+n)} = \frac{1}{N+1} - \frac{1}{2N+1} = \frac{N}{(2N+1)(N+1)}. $$